# Format packages vertically in pacman

Tags: pacman

Suppose I don't upgrade my system for a while. Once I finally run `pacman -Syu`, I'll obviously get lots of packages. In cases like this, the output is completely unacceptable - all packages are written in one line without any kind of alignment, only simple wrapping.

So, can I get `pacman` to show the packages in columns like `ls -C`, or at least vertically like `ls -1`?

So far I've been using `pacman -Syu --print-format '%n %v'`, but this is suboptimal (especially that passing `--print-format` forces `pacman` to run in dry-run mode, so I actually need to run `pacman -Syu` again after examining the packages). Writing a wrapper script, or switching to another frontend, feels like overkill.

Comment: Why is `pacman -Syu --print-format '%n %v'` suboptimal ?

Comment: Because of what I've said in the post, + that's a lot of keystrokes to type. Creating an alias for this will need to have different name than `pacman` to avoid name conflicts, and now your package manager has two entry points: `pacman` and `your_alias`. And having multiple entry points for package managers reminds me of debian's `aptitude`, `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and `dpkg` madness.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than making `pacman` print in columns (or a single column), it is possible to tell `pacman` to print package in **tables** (think `ls -l`). That alone should make the package list itself much more readable.

This behavior can be turned on by uncommenting **`VerbosePkgLists`** option under `[options]` section in `/etc/pacman.conf`. There is no command line switch for this.

Before:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) pacman-mirrorlist-20151115-1  pam-1.2.1-3  taglib-1.10-1

Total Download Size:    0.96 MiB
Total Installed Size:   4.65 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      -0.51 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

After:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (3)             Old Version  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

core/pacman-mirrorlist  20151109-1   20151115-1     0.00 MiB       0.00 MiB
testing/pam             1.2.1-2      1.2.1-3       -0.65 MiB       0.59 MiB
testing/taglib          1.9.1-1      1.10-1         0.13 MiB       0.36 MiB

Total Download Size:    0.96 MiB
Total Installed Size:   4.65 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      -0.51 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Ok, they **do** display vertically (and also show more upgrade info, which is nice) but the display is still confusing because the packages are not displayed sorted by package name,  so I still have to read line-by-line each one to see if a package I'm interested will be upgraded or not.